# Why is the BloC model information updated in this case?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Creating a page to edit a user's profile I initialize a variable with the user's information stored in a model and create a user with that information to edit it:

```
late UserModel user;
late UserModel userUpdate;

@override
void initState() {
   user = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).user;
   UserModel userUpdate = new UserModel(
      id: user.id,
      phones: user.phones
   );

   super.initState();
}
```

I display the phones in a list next to a button that deletes the phone of my choice. The onpressed button does exactly this:

```
onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
      userUpdate.phones.remove(userUpdate.phones[index]);
   });
},
```

In the appBar there are 2 options, return without saving and save.
If I choose the option without saving, I simply do a Navigator.pop(context);

Here is my problem, when deleting a phone from the list, I expect it to be removed from the userUpdate object and when returning without saving nothing happens. However, if I go back to the edit user profile page, that phone has been removed from the main model, the one I initialize in the user variable. Why does this happen?

Summary: I edit an object '2' created from object '1', update a value of object '2' and object '1' is updated.

Comment: The code you show would not show this behaviour, it would throw an exception. Please post a [mcve], either we are missing an important piece of your code, or you did not post the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in count the code you've shared, this variable `late UserModel userUpdate;` is never assigned, because is being shadowed in the `intState` by this other assignment `UserModel userUpdate = new UserModel(...`.

I think it should be `this.userUpdate = new UserModel(...`.

Answer (score 0):

`userUpdate` you created inside initState() cannot call outside this,

create other user variable if you want use

```
late UserModel user;
late UserModel userUpdate;
UserModel defaultUser = UserModel(
      id: user.id,
      phones: user.phones
   );

@override
void initState() {
   user = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context).user;
   super.initState();
}
```